# Como definir o número de clusters no algoritmo Kmeans no R?

Tags: r, k-means

Estou estudando o algoritmo de agrupamento `Kmeans`, e como base de dados para esse meu estudo, estou usando a base `iris`.

```
base = iris
```

O algoritmo em si consegui utilizar sem problemas:

```
base2 = base[3:4]

kmeans = kmeans(x = base2, centers = 3)

previsoes = kmeans$cluster

library(cluster)
clusplot(base2, previsoes, color = TRUE)

table(base$Species, previsoes)

            previsoes
              1  2  3
  setosa     50  0  0
  versicolor  0  2 48
  virginica   0 46  4
```

Como a base iris é relativamente pequena e muito conhecida, sabemos que ela possui três grupos de espécies (setosa,versicolor e virginica), pelo o mesmo motivo que no campo "centers" coloquei o valor 3.

Mas vamos supor que eu não conheça os grupos de espécies da base iris e que essa base é muito grande para analisar visualmente. Como posso definir o número de clusters para o algoritmo Kmeans no R?

Comment: Uganda as funções `unique(iris$Species)` ou `levels(iris$Species)`?

Comment: Desculpe @Willian Vieira, não entendi sua pergunta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontrar o número ideal de clusters não é uma tarefa trivial. Em geral, tarefas de aprendizagem não-supervisionada são complicadas de resolver justamente porque não sabemos a resposta do problema. Lógico, ao usar o conjunto de dados `iris` já sabemos quantas são as espécies de plantas presentes, mas no mundo real, uma tarefa de clusterização não nos dá esta informação.

Felizmente, há métodos que podem ser utilizados para sugerir uma solução. Uma maneira de tentar encontrar o número ideal de clusters em uma tarefa assim é utilizando os pacotes `NbClust` e `factoextra`. Vou ilustrar três métodos deste pacote aqui nesta resposta.

```
base <- iris

base2 <- base[3:4]

library(NbClust)
library(factoextra)

fviz_nbclust(base2, kmeans, method = "wss")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O primeiro método é o `wss` (ou *within sum of squares*). Ele utiliza a soma de quadrados para encontrar o número ideal de clusters. A maneira sugerida para fazer isso é um tanto subjetiva: procure o cotovelo no gráfico acima (isto é, o ponto no qual ele estabiliza) e este é o número sugerido de clusters. No caso deste exemplo, são 3.

```
fviz_nbclust(base2, kmeans, method = "silhouette")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método da silhueta, que calcula as distâncias de cada ponto em relação a todos os outros pontos da amostra, nos dá outro valor: 2 clusters apenas. Ele parece não separar bem as espécies *versicolor* e *virginica*.

```
fviz_nbclust(base2, kmeans, method = "gap_stat")
```

Por fim, o método gap calcular as dispersões dentro de cada cluster e acaba, neste caso, concordando com o método wss, sugerindo novamente 3 clusters.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Portanto, não há uma maneira definitiva de afirmar qual o número ótimo de agrupamentos em uma análise como esta. O que eu faço, ao abordar um problema assim, é aplicar os três métodos e escolher o valor que mais se repete como o número ótimo de clusters. No caso deste exemplo, este valor é 3.

Se os três valores divergirem, aí eu tento conversar com um especialista da área, para ver o que ele acha que é mais condizente com a realidade. Se não houver um especialista da área disponível, eu tento justificar a minha decisão baseado em critérios subjetivos. Por exemplo, eu listaria os elementos pertencentes a cada grupo e tentaria justificar porque 3 grupos são melhores do que 2 ou do que 4, caso eu tenha três resultados diferentes.

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez por responder @Marcus Nunes, não dá nem pra chamar isso de resposta, foi praticamente um artigo científico rsrsrsrs

Answer (score 1):

Além dos pacotes mencionados pelo sempre solícito @MarcusNunes, também há o `ClusterR` que pode ser utilizado para estimar o número de clusters dos dados usando o critério AIC (informações de Akaike) ou BIC (informações bayesianas).

```
    library(ClusterR)

    best_Knumber <- Optimal_Clusters_KMeans(iris[-5], max_clusters = 10, criterion = "BIC",seed = 1234,max_iters = 10,plot_clusters = T)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que foi retirado a variável nominal `iris[-5]`. O número máx de cluster foi fixado em 10 (`max_clusters = 10`), como critério usei o Bayesian Information Criterion mas pode ser utilizado também o "AIC". A literatura em geral afirma que 10 iterações são suficientes para convergência e por fim: `plot_cluster = T` dará a visualização do gráfico.

No caso de seleção de modelo, entre um número específico de modelos, o modelo com o BIC mais baixo deve ser preferido, o que é verdade aqui para um número de clusters iguais a 4.

Não esqueça que como o @MarcosNunes mencionou no início da resposta, Kmeans é uma técnica não-supervisionada e portanto, o número ideal de clusters será sempre baseado na profundidade do analista em conhecer os seus dados a atribuir significado a eles.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @gleidsinmr, vou testar. Foi uma verdadeira aula de vocês dois.

Comment: Na CRAN Task Views vc pode procurar em cluster que vai estar lá reunido, todos os pacotes destinado a tarefas de clusterização. Não deixe de passar lá!

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/            #na parte esquerda abaixo do nome CRAN tem o link (task views          # Quando abrir o link vai aparecer um monte de interesses..   o quarto deles é cluster... clicando novamente vai abrir uma janela com todos os pacotes.